# RingCentral incoming call notification

Tags: c#, ringcentral

I am developing a winform application to get incoming call notification in real time. I am getting error on authorise method

[image]
Below is my code snippet

```
 private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //rc = new RestClient(txtClientID.Text, txtClientSecrete.Text, !chkIsSandBox.Checked);
        rc = new RestClient(txtClientID.Text, txtClientSecrete.Text);
        await  rc.Authorize(txtUsrName.Text, txtExtension.Text, txtPWD.Text);

        RegisterSubscription();


    }

    async void RegisterSubscription()
    {
        var subscription = rc.Restapi().Subscription().New();

        //subscription.EventFilters.Add("/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/message-store");

        subscription.EventFilters.Add("/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/presence");

        subscription.PresenceEvent += subscription_PresenceEvent;

        await subscription.Register();
    }

    void subscription_PresenceEvent(object sender, SubscriptionEventArgs e)
    {
        rtLog.Text += e.Message;
    }
    private async Task<TokenInfo> Authorize()
    {

        return await rc.Authorize(txtUsrName.Text, txtExtension.Text, txtPWD.Text);

    }
```

I would like to receive notification for incoming call.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll bring this to the attention of the maintainer of the C# SDK. Looks like this is a [C# SDK issue](https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-csharp-client) since the error is `Cannot load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0...`

Comment: I have already raised issue over there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for posting your answer on GitHub, Shridhar. I posted it here so people can find it if they run into the same issue:

> I was able to resolve this by adding assembly to the GAC using `Gacutil.exe`.

https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-csharp-client/issues/32